# SVG ViewBox is not loading

Tags: svg, viewbox

I've implemented an `SVG` script in a Wordpress theme to load a certain shape, the svg loads fine however the `viewBox` isn't loading at all which makes the shape looks creepy.

The `$svg` is the attachment id to load.

```
<script>
    var <?php echo $e ?> = Snap("#categories > .categories-container .<?php echo $cat ?>");
    var <?php echo $cont ?> = jQuery(".<?php echo $cat ?>").get(0);
    var <?php echo $width ?> = jQuery(".<?php echo $cat ?>").width();
    var <?php echo $height ?> = (<?php echo $width ?>) / 3;
    <?php
    if($i==1 || $i==2)
    {
        $svg = 456;
    }
    else
    {
        $svg = 456;
    }
    ?>
    var maxHeight = 0;
    
    Snap.load("<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $svg ) ?>", function(<?php echo 'svg' . ($i+1) ?>) {
        <?php echo $e ?>.append(<?php echo 'svg' . ($i+1) ?>);
        <?php
            if($i==1 || $i==2)
            {
               echo "var startpoints = [0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100];";
               echo "var endpoints = [0, 50, 100, 50, 100, 100, 0, 100];";

        ?>
        <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg").attr({viewBox:[0,0,100,100].join(',')});
        <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg").attr({viewBox:[0,0,100,100].join(' ')});
        <?php
            }
            else
            {
                echo "var startpoints = [0, 100, 150, 0, 150, 100, 0, 100];";
                echo "var endpoints = [0, 50, 150, 50, 150, 100, 0, 100];";
            }
        ?>

        <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg > g > g").polygon({
            points: startpoints,
            fill: 'url(#linear-gradient)',
            fillOpacity: 0.9
        });

        if (<?php echo $i ?> === 0)
            <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg > g > g > g > image").attr("class", "maxHeight");

        <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg > g > g > g > image").attr({
            width: 150,
            height: 100
        });

        var maxHeight = 0;
        if (<?php echo $i ?> === 1){
            maxHeight = jQuery(".category1").height();
            jQuery(".introduction").height( maxHeight - 5 );
        }
        else if (<?php echo $i ?> === 2)
            maxHeight = jQuery(".category2").height() * 2 + 12;

        if (<?php echo $i ?> === 1 || <?php echo $i ?> === 2) {

            <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> > svg").attr({
                preserveAspectRatio: "none",
                width: "100%",
                height: maxHeight / 2 - 6,
                background: 'url(im)',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                backgroundSize: "cover",
                backgroundPosition: "center",
            });

        }

        <?php echo $cont ?>.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
            <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> polygon").stop().animate({
                points: endpoints
            }, 500, mina.easein);
        });
        <?php echo $cont ?>.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
            <?php echo $e ?>.select(".<?php echo $cat ?> polygon").stop().animate({
                points: startpoints
            }, 500, mina.easein);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why are there two lines of code that set the viewBox with slightly different syntax (space vs comma separated)? Both spaces and commas are OK.

Comment: Because we're using $i and the total number of items is odd thus we're setting the $i2 and $i3 to shape both as 1 $i1 as sizing